# Python how do i accurately schedule one time tasks

Tags: python, queue, task, scheduler, jobs

so i have this python app and i need to schedule tasks on specific datetimes.

I was thinking something like:

```
    scheduler.add(datetime,func())
```

which would call function func at the specified date and time but accurately. I want seconds or even milliseconds accuracy.

I searched and found the "scheduler" module and tried it but you can only use it with hh:mm format instead of hh:mm:ss.

I hope i am clear

Answer (score 4):

The [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sched.html) module from the standard library uses `time.time` by default, which has pretty good precision*. It has a similar API to the one you're describing:

```
import sched
from datetime import datetime

s = sched.scheduler()
s.enterabs(datetime(2018, 1, 1, 12, 20, 59, 0).timestamp(), 1, func)
s.enterabs(datetime(2018, 1, 1, 12, 20, 59, 500000).timestamp(), 1, func)
s.run()
```

This program will run func on 2018-01-01 at 12:20:59, then again half a second (500000 microseconds) later, then quit.

Of course, you can use any way of getting a timestamp, including parsing a `datetime` from a string and working from there, or just entering a timestamp directly.

---

*: On Linux and Mac, precision of `time.time` is around 1µs. On Windows, it is around 16ms. It is guaranteed to be at least 1 second.

Comment: I had to use s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep) for you code to work on my python distribution. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in `func`, you should add `time.sleep(s)` to the start, so you can be accurate to the second. Also, when passing in a function, pass `func` not `func()`, as `func()` returns a value, and `func` is a function